# Float size, matrix multiplication, OpenCL, sockets. Weird

Tags: c, sockets, opencl

I'm generating two matrices using the following function (note some code is omitted):

```
srand(2007);
randomInit(h_A_data, size_A);

void randomInit(float* data, int size)
{
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < size; ++i){
 data[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
 }
}
```

This is called for matrix A and B. This populates the matrices with 0.something values, e.g. 0.748667. I then perform a matrix multiplication using a CPU. I compare the result to a GPU implementation via OpenCL. The resulting matrix has values in the range 20.something, e.g. 23.472757. Both the CPU and the GPU give the same result. The CPU implementation is taken from the Cuda toolkit distrib by nvidia:

```
void computeGold(float* C, const float* A, const float* B, unsigned int hA, unsigned int wA, unsigned int wB)
{
unsigned int i;
unsigned int j;
unsigned int k;
for (i = 0; i < hA; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < wB; ++j) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < wA; ++k) {
            double a = A[i * wA + k];
            double b = B[k * wB + j];
            sum += a * b;
        }
        C[i * wB + j] = (float)sum;
    }
```

}

The weird thing is, all three matrices in memory are of the same size, i.e. sizeof(float)*size_A, or *size_B for matrix B etc. When I dump them to the disk, the file for the result stored in matrix C (the multiplied matrix) is bigger than matrix A and B.

Even more critical, for my application I'm transferring these over a network via a socket. In terms of the raw number of bytes, all matrices are the same, and yet it takes longer to transfer matrix C over the network. The problem is extrapolated for large matrix sizes. Why is this?

UPDATE/EDIT:

```
fprintf(matrix_c_file,"\n\nMatrix C\n");
   for(i = 0; i < size_C; i++)
   {
      fprintf(matrix_c_file,"%f ", h_C_data[i]);
   }
fprintf(matrix_c_file,"\n");
```

When matrix A and B contain only zero's, all three (matrix A, B and C) are the same size on disk.

Comment: UPDATE: The observations on network transfer time were incorrect. In fact the time taken to pass the buffers over a socket are the same. But I'm still stumped as to why its larger on disk?

Comment: We need to know how you're writing those matrices to disk, since there must be the bug.

Comment: you're using text, so you should expect the file sizes to differ[??]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [lijie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288222/lijie) has the correct (albeit terse) answer in the comments.  The `%f` format specifier can result in a string with variable width.  Consider the following C code:

```
    printf("%f\n", 0.0);
    printf("%f\n", 3.1415926535897932384626433);
    printf("%f\n", 20.53);
    printf("%f\n", 20.5e38);
```

which produces:

```
0.000000
3.141593
20.530000
2050000000000000019963732141023730597888.000000
```

All of the output has the same number of digits after the decimal point (6 by default), but a variable number to the left of the decimal point.  If you need the textual representation of your matrix to be a consistent size and you don't mind sacrificing some precision, you can use the `%e` format specifier instead to force an exponential representation like `2.345e12`.